# Node.js + Express Business Logic Placement

Tags: node.js, sockets, model-view-controller, directory-structure

I am working on an Node.js + Express App that can be found [here](https://github.com/domfarolino/angular2-login-seed) and I am using Sequelize for my database modeling and abstraction. I am at the point where I need my routes to do a slightly more sophisticated things. I want them to be able query different tables in the databases and be able to handle different offsets and limits for query results. Currently my `routes` folder structure looks like this:

```
.
├─routes
│   ├─api
│   │   ├─users.js
│   │   ├─index.js
│   ├─authenticationHelpers.js
│   ├─index.js
```

I wrote a basic `authenticationHelpers.js` module to act as something to validate each request, and if there is no valid session data in the request, return json saying you are not authenticated, or in some cases redirect the user to new view. However I would like my `users.js` and future modules to have an endpoints sophisticated enough to take in a `limit` or `offset` query parameter, and return the last `limit` users in the database. I have this logic very semantically typed out in the `users.js` module and it looks like this:

```
// /users
router.get('/', authenticationHelpers.isAuth, function(request, response) {
  /**
   * Get user count and then calculate our
   * offset as the count - offset
   */
  return models.User.count().then(function(count) {
    var offset = request.query.offset || count;
    /**
     * Get the last 'offset' users
     * in the database.
     * TODO: Make this a cleaner implementation *temporary* 
     */
      models.User.findAll({
        offset: count-offset
      }).then(function(users) {
        var returnUsers = [];
        /**
         * Prune users object for public display
         * TODO: break this out to some sort of data logic utility
         * function for seamless reusability
         */
        users.forEach(function(user, i) {
          user = {
            "name": user.name.split(" ")[0],
            "username": user.username,
            "profile_picture": user.profile_picture,
            "last_active": user.last_active
          }
          returnUsers.push(user);
        });

        response.json(returnUsers); // set response

      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.json(error);
      });

  }).catch(function(error) {

  });

});
```

Couple issues I have with this:

- I get a warning when hitting this endpoint, something along the lines that I am creating a promise within a handler, but never returning the promise. It makes total sense, however acts as an even more motivating factor to push some of this logic out to a business logic layer that would be responsible for returning the appropriate data from the models.
- I have some very reusable logic in here, such as pruning the users object to only consist of attributes I wish to have publicly displayed. I definitely don't want this re-written in every route implementation, plus I'd like some modules to handle it based off of different levels of data allowance. Perhaps if a user is not logged in they can only see 2 public user attributes, if you are the user's friend you can see 4, and if you are the user you can see 7 and so on. That requires more complex authentication and model querying logic, providing me with another motivating factor to push this logic outwards from just the routes.
- I also want to integrate sockets.io into this app very shortly and to do so I will be using some middleware to connect sockets to express sessions so I can push things to the client dependent on their login and view status. This means I am going to need some logic for the sockets that I'd rather not house inside the `app.js` or `www` modules, and I'll want them to be closely coupled with my Sequelize models as well as the business logic that manages them. This would not be easy if all the business logic gets handled in each route implementation.

I want to make sure this application is very well structured from the beginning so that I can really build off of it well in the near future without digging myself into a hole. I am looking for some advice on how to break out some of the business and socket logic for this app.

I'm thinking about creating another directory alongside the `routes` and `models` called either `Controllers`, `Server Logic`, `lib`, or something of the sort to house this sort of thing, and basically build business logic and utility modules so that I can just call them from all of my routes and they'll do their thing, and return the necessary information. Any advice on doing this and the most logical place to put something like this is what I'm looking for.